# How to add custom status values to Team Foundation Server 2018

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am trying to customize the available statuses for various work item types in my on premises Team Found Server 2018 installation.  I cannot find any detailed instructions on how to do this.  I have done this in other versions and it was very simple.  Any information on how this can be accomplished would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: More information of On-premises XML process customization, you can refer to the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS 2018 uses XML process templates. Detailed information you find here: [Customize a process template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/process-templates/customize-process?view=azure-devops). Additionally, you can use Process Template Editor extension for Visual Studio that you can find here [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor) or through VS Extensions:

[image]

TFS Process Template Editor makes the edit process more easy. Here you can the video: [Customize Team Foundation Server Process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ylfJTEMByO4)

You can open find the `Process editor` menu item and open a work item type from an existing team project:

[image]

Select it from the list:

[image]

You can find and edit the states of the work item on the Workflow page:
[image]

Add new states and transitions between them with toolbox:

[image]

Then just press the save button.

Comment: I searched for this in Visual Studuio 2019 and it does not exist.  The only one that does exit is simply called Process Template Editor.  I have already downloaded this extension and cannot find instruction on where / how to edit the statuses field in this tool

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr, yes, for VS 2019 - Process Template Editor. You can find some explanation on video from my answer and I`ve added step to open workflow.

Comment: @ShanriaAleksander - Thank you - I am slowly getting it.  Is there a way to add new fields to the overall project so I don't have to recreate them in each workflow?

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr No. Additionally, we have to update Process Template to include changes for the new team projects: [Upload or download a process template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019)

Comment: @ShanriaAleksander  OK Great - Thanks for your help.  Not quite as straight forward as I hoped but I got it working.